# Asana: Possibility to bookmark users tasks

Tags: asana

I would like to add link from mine application to users tasks in asana.

What I found out asana has a following URL for user tasks:

https://app.asana.com/0/{SOME_ID}/{SOME_ID}

Unfortunately SOME_ID is not a user id, but it is something different.

Is there a possibility to get this ID (SOME_ID) through asana rest API ?

And what exactly SOME_ID means ?

Answer (score 0):

The first ID represents the the user's "Assigned to me" project, which we don't actually expose in the API currently. If you want to get the tasks assigned to a user in a workspace, you can GET `/tasks?workspace=X&assignee=X`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I am already using this URL to get users tasks. But the problem is that I am not displaying tasks in mine application but only count how many overdue/pending tasks "asana user" has, and if one would like to see the tasks he should click the "see details" link which go to the asana app and show the tasks. Do you know if this is possible ?

Comment: Or to ask differently: is it possible to create "URL" in custom application which points me to users tasks, I assume that I would like to build such URL dynamically using your REST api ?

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood. Unfortunately since we don't currently expose the ID of the user's "Assigned to me" project this isn't possible, but it's something we're looking at evaluating. Since the "Assigned to me" project behaves differently from a normal project we're trying to be careful to do this in a way that acts "sane". ;-)

Comment: Hi Asana, we would like to use that ID too because we're building an external app and we need url to open the task.  Actually, we build the url using TASKID/TASKID, and you redirect us to the good url... if there's no project and tag, you build the url with "FIRST_TAG_ID"/TASKID, and if there's a project, we get "PROJECT_ID / TASKID".  But, when there's no project, the window that is opened is quite strange, we see the tasks assigned to a tag, and that's not what we wanted.  We would really like to get that secret project_id too.  Is it always WORKSPACE_ID+2?